# Typecast variable basing on parameters

Tags: c, casting, typecasting-operator

In C, I want to typecast a variable to different variable basing on Variable. How do I make it dynamic? Like

Greedy way

```
    if ( typecast_to_uint16 == 1 ) {
            uint16 v = (uint16)val;
    } else if (typecast_to_char == 1) {
            char p = (char )val;
    } else if (typecast_to_some_struct_a == 1) {
            struct a b = (struct_a)val;
    }
```

This is a greedy way, Is there any Optimized or Dynamic way where I can typecast a variable directly something like using a struct ??

Like eg:

```
     (type_cast_array[struct_a_index]) ret_val;
```

Editing the question to clear confusion..

Comment: Curious, what would be the return type then?

Comment: You can use possibly use [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Comment: Excuse me but how can a function return different types? Are you returning a`void *`? In this case there is no need to cast the result.

Comment: If you're using typecast_to_uint16 as a boolean, then just say `if (typecast_to_uint16) { }`. You don't need to compare it explicitly to 1 if it's a true/false, 1/0 flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done without runtime checks, and you have to do those yourself.

C is a static compiled language, and does not support manipulating types as first class values. That is, you can't put the type of a variable in a different variable and e.g. cast to that type indirectly.

This is because the actual machine code that manipulates values is generated at compile-time, and the compiler has to know the types of things in order to generate the proper instructions.

As mentioned in comments, a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) is often a way to model variables of varying type cleanly.